# Make Google Maker like a Toggle Button

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-markers

Actually i am adding iconview to marker and change to another iconview when one tap on that marker. this can be easily done by adding iconview in `didTapMarker` delegate method. But How to change to default view when one select to another Marker. just like Toggle Button

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    for(int i=0;i<lat.count;i++)
    {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[lat objectAtIndex:i]doubleValue],[[longit objectAtIndex:i]doubleValue]);
        GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position];                        
        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 69, 60)];            
        UILabel * label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 69, 21)];           
        label.text = @"Hello";            
        label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];            
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;            
        label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:24.0/255.0 green:59.0/255.0 blue:91.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];            
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:177.0/255.0 green:177.0/255.0 blue:177.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];            
        UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 21, 69, 38)];            
        [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"map2_"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];                        
        [view addSubview:label];            
        [view addSubview:btn];            
        marker.iconView = view;
        marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop;    
        marker.map = _mapView;            
    }
}
```

and in `didTapMarker` delegate method

```
-(BOOL) mapView:(GMSMapView *) mapView didTapMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker
{        
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 69, 60)];        
    UILabel * label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 69, 21)];        
    label.text = @"Hello";
    label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];        
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;        
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];        
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:32.0/255.0 green:139.0/255.0 blue:58.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];        
    UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 21, 69, 38)];        
    [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"map3_"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];                
    [view addSubview:label];        
    [view addSubview:btn];        
    marker.iconView = view;       
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: just identify your markers uniquely inside the method **didTapMarker** and do your  custom stuff accordingly ..

Answer (score 1):

You can `userData` property of `GMSMarker` for that, first set the userData with all your marker, so add this line inside your for loop of `viewDidLoad` where you are adding marker on `Map`.

```
marker.userData = @{@"isSelected":[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]};
```

Now on `didTapMarker` check like this

```
-(BOOL) mapView:(GMSMapView *) mapView didTapMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker
{

    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 69, 60)];

    UILabel * label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 69, 21)];

    label.text = @"Hello";


    label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];

    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:32.0/255.0 green:139.0/255.0 blue:58.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];

    UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 21, 69, 38)];
    NSNumber *number = [marker.userData objectForKey:@"isSelected"];
    if ([number integerValue] == 0) {
         [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"map3_"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         marker.userData = @{@"isSelected":[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]};
    }
    else { 
         [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"map2_"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         marker.userData = @{@"isSelected":[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]};
    }

    [view addSubview:label];

    [view addSubview:btn];

    marker.iconView = view;

    return YES;
}
```